# Stylesheets in new Spring MVC 4

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-boot

I started a new web project in Spring MVC 4(Spring Boot) and my question is where I must put my css files? I'm using thymeleaf template engine and my folder structure as in picture[image]

as can u see, I trying create a CSS folder under the resources folder, but the link `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/main.css" />` from index.html is not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [the howto docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto):

> Spring Boot by default will serve static content from a folder called /static (or /public or or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServeltContext.

There's also a sample or two, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-ui/src/main/resources/static).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are packaging your project as a `war` in your `pom.xml`.

The `/src/main/resources` folder is usually deployed to `WEB-INF/classes`, so it won't be accessible directly from the context.

However, The `/src/main/webapp` is normally deployed to `/` (root of your web app), which is accessible from the context.

You should put your web resources under `/src/main/webapp` (e.g. `/src/main/webapp/css`). These are then automatically deployed under the context root of your web application. They are then accessible from e.g. `/css`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
```

I'd also move your templates to `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates`.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Notice the OP references he's using Thymeleaf. Its documentation states that `templates` folder must remain at `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the SpringBoot documentation you will see that Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

You have created folder named "css" and you put your file "main.css" inside this folder.
So you should use relative path when referencing this file inside your HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
```